Как тестировать микросервисы в тестовом окружении по rest API?
Используется микросервисная архитектура, где-то 15 микросервисов,между собой общаются по rest API, стоит задача написать автотесты для проверки каждого микросервиса и в планах end2end. И тут возникли споры, чтобы проверить какой-то сервис, для него нужно подготовить данные, если дёрнуть напрямую ручку, она может долго отрабатывать, так как есть взаимодействия с очередями, которые иногда могут отваливаться или ещё какие то сетевые проблемы, было предложение вставлять заранее готовые данные в БД и тестировать, но тогда чем это отличается от моков, так можно и в самом приложении написать интеграционный тест с embeded БД и замочить ответы от других сервисов. Вот и вопрос какой подход используется для написания автотестов? Как можно тестировать микросервис в тестовой реальной среде по rest API?
